# explain slot use in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

`<template #content="{ item }"> // // </template>` 
I come across this code and it seem that `<template #content="{ item }">` is **syntactic sugar** for `<template v-slot:content>` but I still can't understand what is that good for (when to use it)? is the component containing this code is the **parent** or the **child**? what does **content** and **item** refer to? when use the tag 
any explanation for all the questions?

`

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: It'd be hard to answer the question better than the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) which is very thorough and clear and includes many helpful code examples.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Following the answer of yoduh, vue documentation have a detailed
> section about this. https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

I try to give a shot, and do a simple example on when you can use a slot.

You have a component, like a card, and you use it at multiple time, but in very different way.
There is my card component, with a header and a footer, and i want exactly the same every time. But my content can have multiples type (list, description, picture..) or design! (The class name noted the function of the content)

```
// components/Card.vue
<template>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="title">My title</div>
  <div class="icon">close</div>
 </div>
 <slot name="content"/>
 <div class="footer">
  <div class="link">See more</div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Now there is my parent:

```
// views/Parent.vue
<template>
 <card>
  <template v-slot="content">
   <ul>
    <li>I can pass everything i want</li>
    <li>And without props!</li>
    <li>The complexity is in my parent</li>
   </ul>
  </template>
 </card>
</template>
```

With this, my `Card.vue` stay easily understandable, if i want to pass a list or something else, i don't need to update the Card.vue. Everything is outside.

If i need some data, i can play with `<template v-slot="content"="{ item }">`.
With that i can mixed and plya with the data on the parent and the child at the same time, i don't need to manage some props and avoid the fact that maybe, my card content have no report between my `Parent.vue` an one others.